# angularjs make json message sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Here is the Json message:

```
 {"title":      {"default":"hello 3", "position":[2,12,0]},
  "description":{"default":"description hello 3", "position":[1,12,0]},
  "option":     [{"default":"1","position":[3,12,0]}, {"default":"2", "position":[0,12,0]}]
 },
```

I am new to angularjs, I am trying to load the json message in ascending order according to the **position** first element by angularjs and print them in html. ("0" means load firstly, so on so far. )

Could someone help me on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'option' is an array that contains two elements, are they supposed to be displayed on the same level as title and description? Is the expected order: Option 2, Description, Title, Option 1 ?

Comment: @tasseKATT yes, that's right

Comment: The easiest soultion is probably to create a new array based on the message. But it's hard to give a good solution without knowing the true use case. Is 'option' going to be the only array in the message or will there be others? Will there be other keys than 'title' and 'description'? Will there be many messages or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CC8BK/7/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="value in data">Default:{{value.title.default}}
        <li ng-repeat="pos1 in value.title.position|orderBy:orderByValue">{{pos1}}</li>Default:{{value.description.default}}
        <li ng-repeat="pos2 in value.description.position|orderBy:orderByValue">{{pos2}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="val in value.option">Default:{{value.option[$index].default}}
            <div ng-repeat="pos3 in val.position|orderBy:orderByValue">{{pos3}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.orderByValue = function (value) {
        return value;
    };
    $scope.data = [{
        "title": {
            "default": "hello 3",
                "position": [2, 12, 0]
        },
            "description": {
            "default": "description hello 3",
                "position": [1, 12, 0]
        },
            "option": [{
            "default": "1",
                "position": [3, 12, 0]
        }, {
            "default": "2",
                "position": [0, 12, 0]
        }]
    }];

});
```